# 二次元マップをpythonを用いて作成したい。

Tags: python, matplotlib

xy平面上に存在するz軸方向への強度を二次元マッピングを用いてグラフ化したいです。
その際データ間の点は補間し滑らかにつなぐことを想像しています。

データはCSV形式で保存しており、1行目はx軸の値、1列目はy軸の値を入れているようなデータです。
各行各列に対応した強度が格納されているような、画像のようなCSVです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[Python, Matplotlibによるデータの可視化](https://ritsuan.com/blog/8849/) に掲載されているコードを流用し、以下のようにしています。

```
import math 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#データ読み込み
p2 =np.loadtxt ('Book1.csv', delimiter=',')

#軸作成
xx,yy= [],[]
x= p2[0,:]
y= p2[:,0]
x=[1:]
y=[1:]

for num in range(len(x)):
    xx.append(x)
for num in range(len(y)):
    yy.append(y)
X=np.array(xx)
Y=np.array(yy).T

#データに次元配列作成
p2 = np.delete(p2,0,1)
p2 = np.delete(p2,0,0)

#描画
plt.contourf(X,Y,p2,100)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

しかし、以下の記述でsyntaxでエラーが出ます。そもそもこの記述の必要性が理解できていません。なくてはいけないのでしょうか。

```
x=[1:]
y=[1:]
```

どうにか、2次元のマッピングができる形にコーディングをお願いしたいです。
またほかに効率のよい方法がございましたらそちらの記述でも構いません。
ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: まずは参考元のソースを改変せずそのまま動かしてみては？
また, NumPyの ndarray (N-dimensional array)は Pythonの listと考え方が異なるところあるので, [NumPy Quickstart Tutorial など](https://numpy.org/learn/) 見てみるのも良いかも

Answer (score 0):

単なる **typo** あるいは **コピーミス** でしょう。

質問のこの部分は：

```
x=[1:]
y=[1:]
```

参照先記事の該当部分では以下のようになっています。

```
y = y[1:]
z = z[1:]
```

だから質問のソースでは以下のようにすれば良いと思われます。

```
x=x[1:]
y=y[1:]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。そこがミスでした。
そこを改良したら描写のところまでは進めたのですが、次にTypeError: Shapes of x (11, 11) and z (14, 10) do not matchと出てしまって描画できません。個数が対応していないというerrorだとおもうのですが、それぞれ確認してみたところ問題なさそうでした。ここもお分かりになられますでしょうか。

Comment: CSVデータの行数・列数が合っていないのかもしれません。質問にもコピーされた参照先記事のCSVデータ画像をテキスト化して使用したら、表示内容が参照先記事と修正した質問ソースで同じ内容となる不思議な(しかも参照先記事の画像とは違う)結果になりましたが、エラーは発生していませんでした。(画像が違うのはPython,numpy,matplotlibの版数がかなり参照先記事と違うので、その影響かもしれませんが) まあそれ自体は今回とは別の新しい現象でしょうから、貴方の使っているCSVデータも提示して新しい質問を起こしてみてください。ちなみにその際は表示されたエラーメッセージを省略せずにすべて記載してください。